# How to set custom Business Process Flow to default in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM 2013 I have created a Business Process Flow. Now I need to set it as the Default Business Process Flow.
Please tell me the way to set it as default business process flow. I will appreciate your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to select Switch Process option from the list. Please see below.

[image]

Then you will select your business process flow from the list to set it as a default one. Please see below.

[image]

Please click on Select button and finally your business process flow will be set as default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to manually select to Biz Process Flow and wanted to show up default one on top of list then you need to set "Order Process Flow" to define order in which it should be shown in selection page.